# No know conversion for argument 1 from sf::Vector2i to const sf::Vector2i<float>&

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to make simple button using SFML library. The button is supposed to change it's text color when I place mouse on it.

```
void Button::updateColor(sf::Vector2i MousePos)
{
    if(sprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(MousePos)) //here is the problem
        text.setColor(color_covered);
    else
        text.setColor(color_uncovered);
}
```

the .contains() function expects

```
const vector2<T>&
```

the exact error is:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'sf::Vector2i {aka sf::Vector2<int>}' to 'const sf::Vector2<float>&'
```

I have tried to change

```
void Button::updateColor(sf::Vector2i MousePos)
```

to

```
void Button::updateColor(const sf::Vector2i& MousePos)
```

this removed the problem with constness, however I still dont know what to do with invalid reference. I dont know how to pass mouse position correctly.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The error message says that the function expects a `Vector2` of `float` but you pass a `Vector2` of `int`.

Comment: the function takes sf::Vector2<T>, I dont know why the compiler tries to match it with <float> instead of <int>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear: you're trying to pass a `Vector2<int>` instead of the expected `Vector2<float>`.

Since `float` != `int`, this isn't going to work. Modify your input variable.

Comment: I added `sf::Vector2f ms(MousePos);` in my Button::updateColor() to build sf::Vector2f from MousePos and passed it to .contains(). Now it works. I thought that contains() can take Vector2i and that I passed it in wrong way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the variable `sprite` is a [`sf::Sprite`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php) object, the [`getGlobalBounds`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a203d2d8087bfdca2ebc3c0485cdb7409) function returns a `FloatRect` which is a `typedef` of `sf::Rect<float>`. *That's* why the `contains` function expects a vector of floats.

So to solve your problem you need a vector of floats.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why It couldn't use <int> version of template

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to convert any type of `Vector2` into another type (e.g.: `Vector2f` into `Vector2i`, or `Vector2u` into `Vector2f` etc.).

```
template <typename TO, typename FROM>
sf::Vector2<TO> toVector2(const sf::Vector2<FROM> &other)
{
    return sf::Vector2<TO>(
        static_cast<TO>(other.x),
        static_cast<TO>(other.y));
}
```

Then, you could rewrite your code as follow:

```
void Button::updateColor(sf::Vector2i MousePos)
{
    if(sprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(toVector2<float>(MousePos))) // no more error
        text.setColor(color_covered);
    else
        text.setColor(color_uncovered);
}
```

Comment: Well nice function, SFML has already many constructors between std and SFML types, but apparently this one is missing. I realized what I did wrong when saw that .contains() returns sf::Vector2<float>

Comment: I was tired of static_cast<>'ing everything when mixing sf::Vector2 types, so this function came in very handy. Also, this was my first really useful attempt with templates, so I'm kinda proud of myself! :D